# Save and use handle to application console output

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, minecraft

I have a server (Bukkit server, written in Java) and I'm runing it on remote Windows XP machine.
I'd use this to launch the server:

```
start start_bukkit.bat
```

This will create new instance of command line with the batch file that cares about the server. However, I wan't to see the server output in command line, and I need to be able to **regain** the access to the realtime output stream (as well as the access to the input, so that I can run commands), when I connect with remote command line manager again.
How would I do this? Is there some command that can get the STD handle of the application, or something similar?

Comment: Why are you using `start start_bukkit.bat` instead of `start_bukkit.bat`? Using remote desktop (RDP) is not an option?

Comment: Because if you launch a console instance and start bukkit in it, the bukkit with be closed once you disconnect from the remote server (I use radmin).

Comment: Check start_bukkit.bat for a line that says `exit` (just that) if so, delete or precede it with rem.  Then try just running `start_bukkit.bat` instead of `start start_bukkit.bat`

Comment: Don't you understand that I need to access the console again when I reconnect? I connect in a way very similar to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're using the [Telnet connection mode](http://www.radmin.com/support/radmin3help/index.html?page=files%2Ftelnet.htm) from [Radmin](http://www.radmin.com/).

This is something similar to `psexec \\REMOTE_PC cmd.exe`. The "Telnet connection mode" just transfers text input to the remote computer's command-prompt and transfers back its responses.

The "Telnet connection mode" creates an (invisible) `cmd.exe` on the remote. First of all there is no way to reconnect to the same `cmd.exe`. After you exit the `cmd.exe` is closed.

Second is that the `cmd.exe` runs on a different level from the desktop-user. All programs started from it **also** run in that level. Those programs **don't interact** with the desktop and you won't see them in "Full Control" (i.e. Desktop-mode). (Try starting a `notepad.exe`, it lingers in processes but is not visible) Reconnecting to an existing `cmd.exe` or program (which you started with `start` is not possible.)

Maybe there is a possibility to use redirection for output and input. It depends on the program if this works. For example if you can change it that input is taken out of a file and output goes to another file you could control it by reading and writing those files.

But as it is now and you want to see (and interact with) the "Bukkit server" you'll need to start it using "Full Control" of Radmin (to see the full desktop of the remote computer). After reconnecting to the desktop your server will still be visibly running.